# Postman - Need help to store a variable from the date value(YYYY-MM-DD) in response by changing the date format to MMM-DD-YYYY

Tags: postman, date-format

I am getting my output in (YYYY-MM-DD). i want to save to an environment variable by changing the date format to MMM-DD-YYYY (Feb-26-2020)

Sample response:

```
{   
     "pickupDate": "2020-02-26",
     "cutOffTime": "20:00:00",
     "accessTime": {
         "hours": 1,
         "minutes": 0
     },
}
```

Using below just to save the date as it is. But help me to change and save it.

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("day1", jsonData.output.options[1].pickupDate);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do that in the `Tests` tab of the Postman app using [moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/):

```
const moment = require('moment')

let jsonData = pm.response.json();
pm.environment.set("day1", moment(jsonData.output.options[1].pickupDate).format('MMM-DD-YYYY'));
```

You would need to bring in the module first and then use `.format()` to change the date to what you want. I've also used the newer Postman syntax as you were still using the older syntax.

Comment: Thank you Danny, it worked for me. And also thank you for the newer syntax !!!